# RestSharp XmlSerializer and generic Lists do not get serialized

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to get and post data to WCF. DeSerialization of complex types is working as expected. However, I've noticed when posting a Request with complex types (specifically generic lists) the count of these lists at the WCF service is always zero. Doing a quick test with the RestSharp XmlSerializer I've noticed the following:

if I try to serialize the following object The list items are not serialized.

```
    var myObj = new SomeObject()
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "Somename",
                        Items = new List<string> {"itemA", "itemB"}
                    };

    var ser = new XmlSerializer(); //RestSharp serializer
    var result = ser.Serialize(myObj);

    return result;
```

The resulting xml:

```
<SomeObject>
  <Name>Somename</Name> 
  <Id>1</Id> 
  <Items>
    <String /> 
    <String /> 
  </Items>
</SomeObject>
```

However, if I use the standard .Net XmlSerializer the result is:

```
- <SomeObject xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Somename</Name> 
  <Id>1</Id> 
- <Items>
  <string>itemA</string> 
  <string>itemB</string> 
  </Items>
  </SomeObject>
```

Do I need to register the .NET XmlSerializer when posting requests with complex types? or am I forgetting something?